# Getting a Cast to ObjectId error when trying to refrence users when creating post (express -sessions, mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

When user logs into the application, I am using express-sessions to verify them, I attach a user_id to the sessions object , this I will use when I am creating a post, to refrence the user who created that post, eventually I want to have all those post a user created , inside a collection, such that I can easily show it on users dashboard.

---

You can recreate the bug by my github: https://github.com/fullstackaccount/auth_cookies-Session,
use the postman information to : create user,login, then try to submit post.
postman Docs: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8427997/SWEB1amP?version=latest

I am attempting to use this solution to create this refrence to posts: 
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-assign-a-user-a-post-with-mongoose-and-express

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME!

---

This is the login:

```
    console.log(req.session);

    if (!req.session.user) {
        /// If the user does not exist , check if they are authenticated by sessions (express sessions makes authorization in headers)
        var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

        if (!authHeader) {
            var err = new Error('You are not authenticated ...');
            res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
            err.status = 401;
            return next(err);
        }
        var auth = new Buffer.from(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');

        var username = auth[0];
        var password = auth[1];

        User.findOne({ username: username })
            .then((user) => {
                if (user === null || user.password !== password) {
                    // Client tried to login and username/password could not be found

                    var err = new Error('Username or Password could not be found');
                    err.status = 403; // 403 = forbidden access
                    next(err);
                } else if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
                    // double check everything is there, though it should be!
                    req.session.user = 'authenticated';
                    req.session.user_id = user._id; // the user.id is being stored in the sessions object alongside with the cookie
                    res.statusCode = 200;
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                    res.end('You are authenticated!');

                    console.log(`req.session.information ==== ${req.session.information}`);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
    } else {
        // we passed the block of user not existing (!req.session.user), so they are auth, nothing to see here.. move along!
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('you are already authenticated my love');
    }
});
```

This is the Post route, here the express-sessions is availiable, I attempt to save the user with their ID but I get an error :

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  title: 'Myposting',
  content: 'hi',
  author: [ 5df8a29be1e23f2d442e8530 ]
}" at path "posts"
```

POST ROUTE:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Checking to see if session is passed =================== ${req.session}`); // session object
    console.log(`Checking to see if req.session.information is passed =================== ${req.session.user_id}`); // mongoDB id of user

    postModel.create(req.body, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
        userModel.findById(req.session.user_id, (error, user) => {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(returnedDocuments);

            let myUser = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user_id);

            // We create an object containing the data from our post request
            const newPost = {
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content,
                // in the author field we add our current user id as a reference
                author: [ myUser ] //ObjectID(req.session.user_id)
            };

            // we create our new post in our database
            postModel.create(newPost, (err, post) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.redirect('/');
                    throw new Error(err);
                }

                // we insert our newpost in our posts field corresponding to the user we found in our database call
                user.posts.push(newPost);
                // we save our user with our new data (our new post).
                user.save((err) => {
                    return res.redirect(`/posts/${post.id}`);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

As per request, post and user model :

POST MODEL :

```
   {
       title: {
           type: String,
           default: 'BreakfastQueenROCKS'
       },
       content: {
           type: String,
           default: 'Booyeah!'
       },
       author: [
           {
               type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
               ref: 'User'
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       timestamps: true
   }
);
```

USER MODEL:

```
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        admin: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        // we refrence the postModel,
        posts: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Post'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Please share schema of postModel

Comment: Please share request data with header for running postman

Comment: So, you need to register a user first, using the body, then when you login you provide the username and password in postman basic authentication, they will send it over headers and log you in, then you can create a post, and see the situation, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `postModel.create` twice? What does the expeted request body look like on this route?

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that, I do not think I need the outer ``` postModel.create(req.body, (error, returnedDocuments) => { ``` block, indeed I was following that guide I  posted and attempted to replicate the logic. It seems now I need to create the object surrounding the codeblock with ```userModel.findById(req.session.user_id, (error, user) => { ``` such that I can modify the user to include the ID of the post that was created. Still trying to peice everything togeather, its very confusing for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue has to do with pushing the post onto the `User` model. What you have is `user.posts.push(newPost);`, which is the whole post object, but the user model defines posts as:

```
        posts: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Post'
            }
        ]
```

So it seems that you only want to store the post ID on the user, so you can simply change the above mentioned line to `user.posts.push(newPost._id);`

With the update it should should look like so:

```
userModel.findById(req.session.user_id, (error, user) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    let myUser = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user_id);

    const newPost = {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        author: [ myUser ]
    };

    postModel.create(newPost, (err, post) => {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
            throw new Error(err);
        }

        user.posts.push(newPost._id);
        user.save((err) => {
            return res.redirect(`/posts/${post._id}`);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: but this would not account for why the Object schema would not accept the id of the user, that error occured a little before this line, though THANK YOU for this, helped catch a bug.

Comment: So the error you posted says that the validation failed at the path `posts` which is only on the user model. Are you getting a different error now?

Comment: No, I was a little confused, it is all cleared now, but actually I did post._id , using the returned document , this was also given to me as advice, on top of this I had 2 create post methods, I removed the most exterior one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution fixed in case anyone needs it :

post model

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

                // We need to find the logged in user, it is passed in the sessions object from userModel when /login is hit
            userModel.findById(req.session.user_id, (error, user) => {

            // We create an object containing the data from our post request
            const newPost = {
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content,
                // in the author field we add our current user id as a reference
                author_id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user_id)
            };

            // we create our new post in our database
        postModel.create(newPost, (error, returnedDocuments) => {
            if (error){
            res.redirect('/');
            throw new Error(error);

            }


                // we insert our newpost in our posts field corresponding to the user we found in our database call
                user.posts.push(returnedDocuments._id);
                // we save our user with our new data (our new post).
                user.save((err) => {
                    return res.redirect(`${returnedDocuments._id}`);
                });
    });


            // this will populate the posts field in our userSchema (which contain the id references to our posts)
            userModel.findById(req.session.user_id).populate('posts').exec((err, user) => {
                console.log('user.posts======',user.posts);
            });
        });
});
```

login code:

```
// User can Login for their account
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session);

    if (!req.session.user) {
        /// If the user does not exist , check if they are authenticated by sessions (express sessions makes authorization in headers)
        var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

        if (!authHeader) {
            var err = new Error('You are not authenticated ...');
            res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
            err.status = 401;
            return next(err);
        }
        var auth = new Buffer.from(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');

        var username = auth[0];
        var password = auth[1];

        User.findOne({ username: username })
            .then((user) => {
                if (user === null || user.password !== password) {
                    // Client tried to login and username/password could not be found

                    var err = new Error('Username or Password could not be found');
                    err.status = 403; // 403 = forbidden access
                    next(err);
                } else if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
                    // double check everything is there, though it should be!
                    req.session.user = 'authenticated';
                    req.session.user_id = user._id; // the user.id is being stored in the sessions object alongside with the cookie
                    res.statusCode = 200;
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
                    res.end('You are authenticated!');

                    console.log(`req.session.information ==== ${req.session.information}`);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => next(err));
    } else {
        // we passed the block of user not existing (!req.session.user), so they are auth, nothing to see here.. move along!
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('you are already authenticated my love');
    }
});
```